# Can't create handler inside thread in SDK 17

Tags: android

I know what this exception mean (UI methods are called in background methods) and I have fixed it on several places. But I have one occurrence that I do not understand. The code runs well on Android 5 and later, but it fails on Android 4.2. Can somebody tell me the reason?

I need to run at startup a code that initializes Preferences:

```
public class LeliMathApp extends Application
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    new FeedPreferencesTask().doInBackground(null);
 }

private class FeedPreferencesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void[] params) {
        log.debug("Loading default values from XML");
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(LeliMathApp.this, R.xml.game_prefs, false);
        log.debug("Defaults are loaded");
        return null;
    }
}
```

And the exception:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:397) ~[na:0.0]
at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417) ~[na:0.0]
at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428) ~[na:0.0]
at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263) ~[na:0.0]
at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:269) ~[na:0.0]
at android.preference.PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(PreferenceManager.java:482) ~[na:0.0]
at android.preference.PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(PreferenceManager.java:441) ~[na:0.0]
at lelisoft.com.lelimath.helpers.LeliMathApp$FeedPreferencesTask.doInBackground(LeliMathApp.java:156) ~[na:0.0]

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197) ~[na:0.0]
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111) ~[na:0.0]
at android.widget.Editor$UserDictionaryListener.<init>(Editor.java:3836) ~[na:0.0]
at android.widget.Editor.<init>(Editor.java:192) ~[na:0.0]
at android.widget.TextView.createEditorIfNeeded(TextView.java:8489) ~[na:0.0]
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1055) ~[na:0.0]
at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:60) ~[na:0.0]
at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:56) ~[na:0.0]
at android.preference.EditTextPreference.<init>(EditTextPreference.java:56) ~[na:0.0]
```

When I run this code in main thread on Android 4.2, it works well. Why does it fail on older Android and it works on new Android?

Comment: which line that gives you the Exception

Comment: PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues, see stacktrace